# How can I convert 3d variable in array with regridded another 1d variable(which is in same array) from netCDF4?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, netcdf

I'm trying to handle netCDF4 file and it has dimensions and variables like this.

```
<xarray.DataArray '/' ()>
array(<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>
root group (NETCDF3_CLASSIC data model, file format NETCDF3):
    Title: Monthly version of HadISST sea surface temperature component
    description: HadISST 1.1 monthly average sea surface temperature
    institution: Met Office Hadley Centre
    source: HadISST
    reference: Rayner, N. A., Parker, D. E., Horton, E. B., Folland, C. K., Alexander, L. V., Rowell, D. P., Kent, E. C., Kaplan, A.  Global analyses of sea surface temperature, sea ice, and night marine air temperature since the late nineteenth century J. Geophys. Res.Vol. 108, No. D14, 4407 10.1029/2002JD002670
    Conventions: CF-1.0
    history: 8/12/2021 converted to netcdf from pp format
    supplementary_information: Updates and supplementary information will be available from http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadisst
    comment: Data restrictions: for academic research use only. Data are Crown copyright see (http://www.opsi.gov.uk/advice/crown-copyright/copyright-guidance/index.htm)
    dimensions(sizes): time(1822), latitude(180), longitude(360), nv(2)
    variables(dimensions): float32 time(time), float32 time_bnds(time, nv), float32 latitude(latitude), float32 longitude(longitude), float32 sst(time, latitude, longitude)
    groups: , dtype=object)
```

Here, I wanted to regrid the longitude grid from (-180, 180) to (0, 360), so I did it using numpy.

And the problem is,

```
In [10]: print(DATA1['sst'])
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 sst(time, latitude, longitude)
    _FillValue: -1e+30
    standard_name: sea_surface_temperature
    long_name: sst
    units: C
    cell_methods: time: lat: lon: mean
    missing_value: -1e+30
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (1822, 180, 360)
filling on
```

that changed longitude affects sst, which is another variable. So I have to do something to SST too, as I've done to longitude. But I do not know what I have to do...
(I'd like to make this with only numpy as long as possible!)

Here, it's what I've made so far

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from sys import exit    
import numpy as np
import pickle

file1= 'HadISST_sst.nc'
DATA1 = Dataset(file1, 'r')
hd_lat = DATA1.variables['latitude'][:] 
hd_lon0 = DATA1.variables['longitude'][:] 
hd_sst0 = DATA1.variables['sst'][1320:,:,:]
DATA1.close()

#Regridding longitude
id = np.where(hd_lon0 == 0)[0]  # <-- id = 180
a = hd_lon0[:180] + 360
b = hd_lon0[180:]
hd_lon = np.zeros_like[hd_lon0]
hd_lon[:180] = b
hd_lon[180:] = a
```

Comment: Where do you see a change in sst?

Comment: sorry for late answer. Before changing the latitude grid, sst was consisted of some lists with float but now it's consisted of some lists with boolean things.